# How to get CIs for predicted summary value after regression in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, stata, statsmodels

I am trying to get confidence intervals around the predicted summary values after a regression and cannot figure out how to do that in python.
I know how to get a prediction and CI for every subject but not for the summary measure. Using the following example my question is:
"What is the average gre level for someone with a gpa of 3:"

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_stata('https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/stata/dae/binary.dta', convert_categoricals=False)
regresult = sm.ols(formula='gre~gpa', data=df).fit()
pred=regresult.get_prediction(df.assign(gpa=3))
predtable=pred.summary_frame()
print(predtable)
print(np.mean(predtable['mean']))
```

I know how to get the summary measure [i.e., np.mean(predtable['mean'])   ], but not how to get the CIs.

Basically I want to replicate the corresponding Stata output of margins but do not know how:

```
use http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/stata/dae/binary.dta
regress gre gpa
margins, at(gpa=3)

. margins, at(gpa=3)

RESULT:
Adjusted predictions                              Number of obs   =        400
Model VCE    : OLS

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()
at           : gpa             =           3

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   542.2223   7.648634    70.89   0.000     527.1855    557.2591
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to get the CI of  527.1855  -  557.2591 in Python?

Best

UPDATE:
As Pearly Spencer points out, in the aforementioned example the respective values can be seen in predtable.
However, this no longer works when a categorical variable is included:

```
regresult = sm.ols(formula='gre~gpa+C(rank)', data=df).fit()
pred=regresult.get_prediction(df.assign(gpa=3))
predtable=pred.summary_frame()
print(predtable)
print(np.mean(predtable['mean']))
```

The Stata commands margins calculates the predicted probability for someone with gpa=3 while setting rank at its mean.

```
. regress gre gpa i.rank
. margins, at(gpa=3)

Predictive margins                                Number of obs   =        400
Model VCE    : OLS

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()
at           : gpa             =           3

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   541.9911   7.640092    70.94   0.000     526.9707    557.0114
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is equal to: margins, at(gpa=3) atmeans

In Python print(np.mean(predtable['mean'])) gives the correct value of 541.9911. However, I do not know how to calculate the CIs.
Perhaps it would work with using pred=regresult.get_prediction(df.assign(gpa=3)) and somehow include the mean of rank after gpa=3 but I could not get it to work because only rank=1, rank=2, rank=3 and rank=4 are allowed since rank is used as a categorical var in the equation.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. The result you want is already in `predtable`. You should be able to see the CI in the output produced by `print(predtable)`.

Comment: Also, why do you use `np.mean(predtable['mean'])`? `predtable.mean()[0]` is enough. I think you should learn more about basic Python objects first.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should have checked that example more thoroughly. The corresponding values can be seen in predtable. However, this no longer works when a categorical variable is included (see my update)

Comment: What do you mean it no longer works? I can see confidence intervals in the Python output when using your new example albeit slightly wider which is probably due to difference in how standard errors are calculated in Python.

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy. Of course, the CIs are computed. However, I would like to get the same CIs as in the Stata output. Stata computes them using the delta method which Python (perhaps) does not. Can this output be achieved in Python somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can implement this manually using Numpy.